# Castle Windsor - LoadFromContext occurred

Tags: c#, exception, castle-windsor, .net-assembly

While trying to load an assembly using this code:

```
mainContainer.Install(FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(@"Dll\Folder").FilterByName(a => a.Name.Equals("My.Dll.ToLoad", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))));
```

I get this error:

> *Managed Debugging Assistant 'LoadFromContext' has detected a problem in 'C:\Dev\MyProgram\Release\MyProgram.exe'.   Additional information:
>   The assembly named 'b.Edge.Domain' was loaded from
>   'file:///C:/Dev/MyProgram/Release/Dll/Folder/Referenced.DLL' using the
>   LoadFrom context. The use of this context can result in unexpected
>   behavior for serialization, casting and dependency resolution. In
>   almost all cases, it is recommended that the LoadFrom context be
>   avoided. This can be done by installing assemblies in the Global
>   Assembly Cache or in the ApplicationBase directory and using
>   Assembly.Load when explicitly loading assemblies.*

Actually the **Referenced.DLL** is referenced by **My.Dll.ToLoad**, and i cannot disable any exception from Visual Studio for work reasons.

So, the point is:
Am I doing something wrong?
Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Thank you in advance for any answer,

Comment: I also get this error when calling `CompositionContainer.ComposeParts`.  Doesn't seem to be a common error.  I have it for only one of several calls.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9610236/2091951